# I need help to move the "camera" over a tunnel in OpenGL

Tags: c, opengl

I created a small scene in C and OpenGL. It is a plane with a small tunnel over it. I'm trying to move the OpenGL "camera" inside this tunnel. However, I've been having some difficult to configure perspective and the objects disapear as I translate the object (my idea was to rotate and translate the scene to enter the tunnel).

I'm trying not to use additional lybraies, such as GLUT.

Can someone help?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <gl/gl.h>

#define sizeX  0.05f
#define sizeY  0.75f
#define incr 0.1

double xyz[3] = {0,0,0};
int op = 0;

void incrAxis(int v){
    if(v != 0)
        xyz[op] += incr;
    else
        xyz[op] -= incr;

    printf("%f %f %f\n",xyz[0],xyz[1],xyz[2]);
}

void changeAxis(int v){
    op = op + v;
    if(op == 3)
        op = 0;
    else
        if(op < 0)
            op = 2;
}


void draw(){
    double alt = -0.1;
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glColor3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);     // black plane
        glVertex3f( 0.275, 0.275, alt);
        glVertex3f( 0.275,-0.275, alt);
        glVertex3f(-0.275,-0.275, alt);
        glVertex3f(-0.275, 0.275, alt);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);     // plane
        glVertex3f( 0.75, 0.75, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f( 0.75,-0.75, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(-0.75,-0.75, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(-0.75, 0.75, 0.0f);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f( sizeX, sizeY, -sizeX);
        glVertex3f( sizeX,-sizeY, -sizeX);
        glVertex3f(-sizeX,-sizeY, -sizeX);
        glVertex3f(-sizeX, sizeY, -sizeX);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-sizeX, -sizeY, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(-sizeX, -sizeY, -sizeX);
        glVertex3f(-sizeX, sizeY, -sizeX);
        glVertex3f(-sizeX, sizeY, 0.0f);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(sizeX, -sizeY, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(sizeX, -sizeY, -sizeX);
        glVertex3f(sizeX, sizeY, -sizeX);
        glVertex3f(sizeX, sizeY, 0.0f);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(-sizeX, sizeY, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(-sizeX, sizeY, -sizeX);
        glVertex3f( sizeX, sizeY, -sizeX);
        glVertex3f( sizeX, sizeY, 0.0f);
    glEnd();

}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
void EnableOpenGL(HWND hwnd, HDC*, HGLRC*);
void DisableOpenGL(HWND, HDC, HGLRC);


int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR lpCmdLine,
                   int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;
    HWND hwnd;
    HDC hDC;
    HGLRC hRC;
    MSG msg;
    BOOL bQuit = FALSE;

    /* register window class */
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = CS_OWNDC;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH);
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName = "GLSample";
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);;


    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
        return 0;

    /* create main window */
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0,
                          "GLSample",
                          "OpenGL Sample",
                          WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                          CW_USEDEFAULT,
                          CW_USEDEFAULT,
                          512,
                          512,
                          NULL,
                          NULL,
                          hInstance,
                          NULL);

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);

    /* enable OpenGL for the window */
    EnableOpenGL(hwnd, &hDC, &hRC);

    /* program main loop */
    while (!bQuit)
    {
        /* check for messages */
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            /* handle or dispatch messages */
            if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
            {
                bQuit = TRUE;
            }
            else
            {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            /* OpenGL animation code goes here */

            glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

            glPushMatrix();
            glTranslatef(xyz[0],xyz[1],xyz[2]);

            glRotatef(89, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            glRotatef(50, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            //glRotatef(5, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

            draw();

            glPopMatrix();

            SwapBuffers(hDC);

            Sleep (1);
        }
    }

    /* shutdown OpenGL */
    DisableOpenGL(hwnd, hDC, hRC);

    /* destroy the window explicitly */
    DestroyWindow(hwnd);

    return msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_CLOSE:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            return 0;

        case WM_KEYDOWN:
        {
            switch (wParam)
            {
                case VK_ESCAPE:
                    PostQuitMessage(0);
                break;
                case VK_RIGHT:
                    changeAxis(+1);
                    break;
                case VK_DOWN:
                    incrAxis(0);
                    break;
                case VK_LEFT:
                    changeAxis(-1);
                    break;
                case VK_UP:
                    incrAxis(1);
                    break;
            }
        }
        break;

        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}

void EnableOpenGL(HWND hwnd, HDC* hDC, HGLRC* hRC)
{
    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd;

    int iFormat;

    /* get the device context (DC) */
    *hDC = GetDC(hwnd);

    /* set the pixel format for the DC */
    ZeroMemory(&pfd, sizeof(pfd));

    pfd.nSize = sizeof(pfd);
    pfd.nVersion = 1;
    pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW |
                  PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
    pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
    pfd.cColorBits = 24;
    pfd.cDepthBits = 16;
    pfd.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;

    iFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(*hDC, &pfd);

    SetPixelFormat(*hDC, iFormat, &pfd);

    /* create and enable the render context (RC) */
    *hRC = wglCreateContext(*hDC);

    wglMakeCurrent(*hDC, *hRC);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);               // Enables Smooth Color Shading
    glClearDepth(1.0);                 // Depth Buffer Setup
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);               // Enables Depth Testing
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);                  // The Type Of Depth Test To Do
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT,GL_NICEST);//Realy Nice perspective calculations


    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    glFrustum(-10, 10, -10, 10, -100, 100);

    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();
}

void DisableOpenGL (HWND hwnd, HDC hDC, HGLRC hRC)
{
    wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
    wglDeleteContext(hRC);
    ReleaseDC(hwnd, hDC);
}
```

Comment: Isn't this code just going to stall while there are WM_ messages incoming? Why aren't you doing this from inside WM_PAINT or from another thread? Also the `Sleep` call only serves one single purpose here: to create lag.

Comment: This is the OpenGL project created by default by CodeBlocks

Comment: So? Don't blindly trust some random open source snippet you found in a packet of corn flakes.

Comment: see [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214) once you grasp the ideas see the links in the end of answer there are examples of camera and player controls (different styles and maths)

Answer (score 1):

I already solved the problem.

I replaced

```
glFrustum(-10, 10, -10, 10, -100, 100);
```

for

```
gluPerspective(45.0,1.0,0.1,200.0);
```

It now works fine.